500.html being displayed on dev instead of an error
I'm working on a really old legacy Rails app and there is one thing someone else implemented several years ago i am not able to deal with. Basically, for any 500-like exceptions raised in the code, my app is rendering 500.html file instead of showing me the actual exception. It basically behaves like i had consider_all_requests_local config set to false in dev env but i don't. It's set to true. Also, i don't have any exceptions_app app configured, i don't use any rescue_from statements that could impact it - i can't see any single place in my codebase that could impact how 500 error pages are displayed.
Do you have any idea where should i look or how can i debug rails behavior regarding that?

Rails: 7.0.8
Ruby: 3.2.3


Just for clarification is Rails.configuration.consider_all_requests_local == false?

Also it's a very old app that has been upgraded to Rails 7.0.8? Is there anything in the gemfile that could be the culprit?

@max consider_all_requests_local is set to true. And yes, it's a very old app upgraded to 7.0.8. Gemfile is massive so it's pretty hard to tell if anything might be interfering
